# Codepen.io, Unexpected number error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and making a simple project in Codepen.io using JSON.
I want to select a random index from the object array and to do this I am using getRandomArbritrary function.
However, in codepen.io I am having the error "unexpected number".
My original code:

```
  $(document).ready (function(){
  function getRandomArbitrary(0,2){
  var x = Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0;
  }
```

Now this is my code after correction:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
function getRandomArbitrary(low,high){
var low = 0;
var high = 2;
var x = Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
return x;
}

function getQuote(){

var obj1 = [ {author: "-Jeremiah 29:11", quote: "For I know the plans I   have for you,” declares the LORD, “plans to prosper you and not to harm   you, plans to give you hope  and a future."},

{ quote: "If God called us to a task, He will then qualify us for the   job."},

{author:"-1Timothy 6:12", quote: "“Fight the good fight of the faith.   Take hold of the eternal life to which you were called and about which you   made the good confession in the presence of many witnesses."},
        ];

$(".quote").text(obj1[x].quote);
$(".author").text(obj1[x].author);
}


$(".button").on("click", function(){
  getQuote();
});
});
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with codepen.io. You can copy that code into your dev console (press [F12]) and you will get the same exception. JavaScript variables cannot start with a digit.

Comment: You're defining a function and using actual numbers as the arguments instead of variables.

Comment: What is that even suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using numbers, give names to the function parameters:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(low, high){
    var x = Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}
```

Most likely, you also want to `return` the result -- right now, the function effectively does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is *nothing** wrong with [Codepen](http://codepen.io), the problem is that you are using **actual numbers** as the function arguments, I.E: you are **literally** typing numbers into the function parenthesis.

Another problem was that you were **not** returning **anything** in your function, so it was practically *useless*. If you would like to have a function return a value you should use the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

Now back to the first problem, you are **not** supposed to **literally** type values into the function parenthesis and you **cannot** supply function arguments in this manner, if you would like to provide the same arguments every time the function is called then you should use this:

```
function getRandomArbitrary() {
  // determine "low" and "high" values (once)
  var low = 0,
    high = 2;
  // calculate the result
  var x = Math.random() * (high - low) + 0;
  // return the result.
  return x;
}
```

If you would like to to supply your own values every time you call the function, then you should use this instead:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(low, high) {
  // calculate the result
  var x = Math.random() * (high - low) + 0;
  // return the result.
  return x;
}
```

Now, when I said: `There is nothing* wrong with Codepen`. Please remember that we can never be 100% sure of this, and if you think there is something wrong with Codepen then you should *really* report what you think is problem to Codepen on their [support](http://codepen.io/support/) page.

I would also like to remind you that the amount of jQuery in your code is *minimal at best*. You might want to check this [JS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cLvpJY2deo) out, it takes only 30 minutes of your time and it got me started with JavaScript and I even reference it every now and then, please make sure you know *at least the basics* of JavaScript **before** you learn jQuery.
I (like thousands of other developers) made this mistake before I understood that **jQuery is a library written in JavaScript**.

If you would like a *hands on* approach, you can learn [JavaScript](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript) & [jQuery](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery) and practice them online **for free** over on [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com):

I've fixed some minor mistakes in your HTML, but overall nothing too *"troublesome"*.
Here is the edited HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Quote Generator =)</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" />
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header"><b>Random Quote Generator</b></header>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="button" value="click me for quote" class="button" />
      <div class="quotes">
        <span class="quote"><h1></h1></span>
        <span class="author"><h1></h1></span>
        <div id="share-buttons">
          <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http://codepen.io/ionakathryn/pen/YWEPkz";text=Random Quote Generator: www.ionakathryn.com&amp; target="_blank">
            <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://twitter.com&amp;text=Random Quote Generator: www.ionakathryn.com&amp;hashtags=FreeCodeCamp" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
          </a>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://codepen.io/ionakathryn/pen/YWEPkz";text= ".quotes"&amp; target=".quotes">
            <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the edited JavaScript:

```
// I've noticed that you might use multiple plugins and / or libraries
// so I've written "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {" so that the "$" variable is definitely assigned to jQuery inside the "document ready"
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // removed the quotes list from the function
  // you can even place it above the "document ready" function
  // or even make the quotes variable a global using "window.quotes =" instead of "var quotes ="
  var quotes = [{
    // changed the "quote" to "text" to make it look a little less confusing inside the click function
    "author": "- Jeremiah 29:11",
    "text": "'For I know the plans I have for you,” declares the LORD, “plans to prosper you and not to harm you, plans to give you hope  and a future.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- anonymous",
    "text": "'If God called us to a task, He will then qualify us for the job.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- 1Timothy 6:12",
    "text": "'Fight the good fight of the faith. Take hold of the eternal life to which you were called and about which you made the good confession in the presence of many witnesses.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- Luke 6:31",
    "text": "'Do to others as you would have them do to you.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- 1 Corinthians 13:13",
    "text": "'And now these three remain: faith, hope and love. But the greatest of these is love.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- 1 John 4:8",
    "text": "'Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- Romans 15:13",
    "text": "'Now may the God of hope fill you with all joy and peace in believing, that you may abound in hope by the power of the Holy Spirit.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- Ecclesiastes 9:10",
    "text": "'Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with all your might.'"
  }, {
    "author": "- Proverbs 12:25",
    "text": "'Anxiety in a man’s heart weighs it down, but an encouraging word makes it glad.'",
  }, {
    "author": "- Mark 9:23",
    "text": "'If you can believe, all things are possible to him who believes.'",
  }];

  // removed the external "getQuote" function as it wasn't unnecessary
  // I'm assuming this because you only use it once
  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    // simplified the process of updating the quote
    var q = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    $(".quote").text(q.text).next().text(q.author);
  });
});
```

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However I was assigning the result of Math.random() to a variable called x then calling this when referring to a JSON object. Please see the link to the project I am working on then it will be more clear of what I want to do:
http://codepen.io/ionakathryn/pen/YWEPkz?editors=0010
Thanks

Comment: @Lona-Kathryn Evans, I understand what you're trying to do, but how would you like me to help you? If you wanted someone to fix your code up then I've updated my answer with updated HTML & JS, and commented it  to make it easer to understand.